# How would you encapsulate the login action of a user so that you can reuse it for your tests when writing Geb/Spock tests for your Grails app?

Tags: grails, groovy, functional-testing, spock, geb

I am beginning to write functional tests with Geb and Spock. I wrote a few simple ones for the login of my application but now, I would like to encapsulate the login process so I can test pages that require authentication.

How would you go about it?

Thanks in advance.

Also, I could not find a google group to post this question, where do people having Geb/Spock  questions go to?

Comment: By reading the tags, I probably won't be able to answer your question, but you should consider adding **relevant code** to your question for those who may be able to answer it.

Comment: Thanks, I see your point, I will next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a great blog post that answered my question:

[Encapsulating page state and actions](http://adhockery.blogspot.com/2010/11/encapsulating-page-state-and-actions-in.html)

The author goes beyond my initial use case and also demonstrate how one would encapsulate and reuse test code around a pagination module for example.

Comment: Do you have a login box on every page, like in the blog? Or were you able to make it work with a redirect for logins?